# Proper joins for multiple tables/left join +

Tags: mysql

Not sure how to work this but I found a way that works although some of the columns have incorrect data in them.  So for now, I'll leave this with a SOLVED indication but I may need this documentation for other assistance. It could be deleted though.

Sorry, but I don't think that the answer lies in the "questions with similar titles".  I could well be wrong but I have searched and searched for documentation I can understand but it's probably like my old days with the IBM manuals for main frames.  If you don't know the exact word you won't find the answer.

So here goes:

```
SELECT * FROM membership LEFT JOIN address2 USING(memno)
CROSS JOIN contact USING(memno)
CROSS JOIN workers USING(memno)
CROSS JOIN comments USING(memno)
JOIN candidates USING(memno)
```

Tried this a number of ways.  I thought about saying I tried it every way possible but I obviously did not do it the right way at least.  When I do just the first line I get all the right columns and I get all five rows of the tables in my db.

When I add the second line it works but I only get two rows.  It works through the "comments" line.  It doesn't do the last line "candidates".

What I need to be getting is all five rows (the number of rows in the membership table).

Cross join is one problem. I think that it limits the rows as there are only two rows in one of the tables and it goes both ways on the limits.

So I think that what I need is the correct JOIN for the second, third, and fourth line and likely another JOIN type for the last line.

I have very limited hair to tear out so I need your help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, without knowing your table schema, data nor having a clear expected result it is a bit difficult to guess what you're looking for. But this will get you all rows from the membership table regardless of whether they have a match or not on the other tables:

```
SELECT * FROM membership
LEFT JOIN address2 USING(memno)
LEFT JOIN contact USING(memno)
LEFT JOIN workers USING(memno)
LEFT JOIN comments USING(memno)
LEFT JOIN candidates USING(memno)
```

**Edit:**

Personally, I wouldn't trust `USING` when using chained left joins like this. I would make sure by explicitly adding the table to join:

```
SELECT * FROM membership m
LEFT JOIN address2 a on m.memno = a.memno
LEFT JOIN contact con on m.memno = con.memno
LEFT JOIN workers w on m.memno = w.memno
LEFT JOIN comments com on m.memno = com.memno
LEFT JOIN candidates can on m.memno = can.memno
```

I *scanned* the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) on `USING` and couldn't find any reference to this, but I meant that I'm not sure from which table it chooses the columns. This:

```
SELECT * FROM membership m
LEFT JOIN address2 a on m.memno = a.memno
LEFT JOIN contact con on m.memno = con.memno
```

Is using alias `m` as the left part of the left join, so I'm sure I'll see all memebers, regardless of the fact that thay have or not a contact or an address. However, this:

```
SELECT * FROM membership m
LEFT JOIN address2 a USING(memno)
LEFT JOIN contact c USING(memno)
```

Is not clear on from what table is using the `memno` when joining with `contact`. In the first left join of the previous example there is no other table to choose so it will join `m` and `a` and `m` will be the left part. But when joining `c` you will have 2 `memno`: `m.memno` and `a.memno`. If the `USING` chooses `m`, then the query will be the same, but if it chooses `c`, the previous query will translate to:

```
SELECT * FROM membership m
LEFT JOIN address2 a on m.memno = a.memno
LEFT JOIN contact c on a.memno = c.memno
```

I think this is not what you're looking for. Don't think it is a bad practice specifying the fields and the tables they come from... the intentions are clearer that way.

Comment: Membership is the main table.  The others are just for variable data that may or not be there for an individual.  Depends on what the users enter.  What I was doing here was trying to see what the tables looked like and to see if the tables were being joined correctly.  I thought I tried what you should me here but I must have messed it up.  I copied this and I will redo my test.  Thanks for this.  I'll update in the next couple of days.

Comment: I don't know if this is the proper way to converse on this forum but here goes. Correct me if this is the wrong way please.  I liked the idea of the USING method because it looked cleaner but that was when I thought I didn't have to repeat it for each JOIN.  I have to try this explicit method after I finish this.

Comment: Before I asked you all how to do what I needed to do I did a lot of searching and reading.  For a novice, which I am where mysql and php are concerned, I think that the mysql official manual is far too technical.  Many of us only want to "get er done" as quickly and efficiently as possible.  The people on this forum mostly talk in plain English which helps "newbies" greatly.  I ran my query with the direct references as you suggested and it worked fine.

Comment: Okay @Mosty, where or how do I mark the answer.  I was looking for something like this to tell all that I got the answer I needed such as [SOLVED].  Is this it? [ACCEPTED]?

Answer (score 0):

The sort of join you need depends on the sort of relationship between the tables. There are two common cases.

The first case is when you're interested in detail records, and you need to refer to master records. Since there is always a related master record, an inner join suffices.

The second case is when you're interested master records, and you need to refer to optional detail record(s). In this case you typically want a left join.

The second case can be split into two sub-cases depending on whether the number of detail records is limited to a maximum of 1 or not but this doesn't affect the type of join used.

Comment: Definitly want the left join.  Problem was adding the various tables.  I am going to try Mostly Mostacho's code.  I got it to work using Ons but I like the "USING" better if indeed it works.  Probably have to be careful with my keying.  Thanks for your help Neil.